# Testing asp.net pages programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, testing

Suggest a testing framework, which could autofill forms, simulate a button click and navigate to next page.

I am trying to automate this task to reduce development time.

EDIT :
From the list suggested by Arran, Coded UI seems to be the most feasible option. (Considering enterprise restrictions, I cannot install new softwares).

Please suggest some directions to write something on my own or using Microsoft Coded UI.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

Microsoft's CodedUI built into Visual Studio Ultimate

Selenium

Watin (Abandonware, somewhat)

Telerik's Testing Framework.

All will get the job done without much fuss.

Comment: any source to backup the claim that Watin is Abandonware?

Comment: @dugas, no, however it does not take a genius to see that there isn't much activity in the project. If you were using a testing framework, do you want a framework that is maintained frequently, or one that is maintained every now and then? Watin works well, I am not denying this.

Comment: @autrevo It is bundled into Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate or Premium, shouldn't need any addins.

Comment: @Arran - that's good that it doesn't require a genius because a genius I am not, but there are revisions to the trunk as recently as 4/5/2012.

Comment: @dugas, that's 5 months ago, hardly recent, but also look the state of the releases: http://watin.org/documentation/. Compare it to Selenium, where commits are every day: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/list. You may like to use software which isn't updated very often, others won't. Make sure people know it's not updated often but it works - I don't see much issue with that.

Comment: @dugas, to go one further, the commits are very few and far between: http://sourceforge.net/p/watin/code/1217/log/

Answer (score 2):

Give [WatiN](http://watin.org/) a look. I have used it in the past and really like it.
Example:

```
[Test] 
public void SomeMethodTest_SelectListOptionPickedAndButtonClicked_TextboxHasExpectedValue()
{
  using (var browser = new IE("http://yourpage.com"))
  {
   browser.SelectList("DdlId").Option("SomeOption").Select();
   browser.Button(Find.ByName("SomeButtonId")).Click();
   string textFieldValue = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("SomeTextFieldid")).Text;

   Assert.AreEqual("ExpectedValue", textFieldValue);
  }
}
```